# Dimensioning a variable inside a loop

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having difficulty dimensioning a key variable in a loop - when I use an absolute cell reference (ie A1) it's fine, but when I dimension a relative value (ie (i,j) ) it fails - even though I can call that value into a cell no problem.

Any thoughts much appreciated...
Cheers
Dan

Example:

**This** works:

```
Sub Test(ARRAYX)

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
With Workbooks("X.xlsb").Sheets("X")

    i = 50 'rows
    Do Until i = 51
        For j = 30 To 650 Step 30    'cols

            Dim NUM as integer

            NUM = activesheet.range("A1")  
            Workbooks("X.xlsb").Sheets("X").Cells(i - 48, j).value = ARRAYX(NUM, 2)
        Next j
        i = i + 1
    Loop
 End With
 End Sub
```

**This** does not work:

```
Sub Test(ARRAYX)

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
With Workbooks("X.xlsb").Sheets("X")

    i = 50 'rows
    Do Until i = 51
        For j = 30 To 650 Step 30    'cols

            Dim NUM as integer

            NUM = Workbooks("X.xlsb").Sheets("X").Cells(i, j).value  
            Workbooks("X.xlsb").Sheets("X").Cells(i - 48, j).value = ARRAYX(NUM, 2)

         Next j
        i = i + 1
    Loop
 End With
 End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value?  Can an integer hold it?

Comment: Yes  - the first code block works perfectly so the problem is entirely in the different method of dimensioning.

Comment: What do you mean by "fails"?  Do you get an error?  If so, what is the error and what line does it throw on? If not, please describe the intended behavior and how your code is "failing" to do that.

Comment: general VBA tip. You have a `With` block, but you're not actually using it.

Comment: Can I ask why you dimension it in the loop and not at the start with the other variables?

Comment: Comintern  - I get an 'OUT OF RANGE' on the last line inside the loop - calling from the array. But, as noted, not with the first example when i call the number from A1.

Comment: @tompreston declaring close to first use is a *good* thing. Being inside a loop is irrelevant. It only dimensions once.

Comment: Hi Tom it changes constantly and there are a large number of them - one to identify each (and to therefore select the corect line in the array).

Comment: @DanS you're confusing the declaration with the assignment.. Declarations execute once, assignments in a loop execute every time

Comment: @ThunderFrame thanks for the pointer, much appreciated

Comment: @DanS just noticed you're referencing a cell in the macro workbook, you need to reference a cell in the actual workbook with extension like .clsx etc

Comment: "Out of Range" as in "*Subscript* out of Range"?  In that case, check the workbook and sheet names for typos.

Comment: Thanks for all the input but I think i have not been clear - the first code works. When I assign an absolute cell reference (ie A1) it works fine. But when I assign from a cell reference WITHIN THE LOOP the array gives me an out of range error.

Comment: I should add that the value has been assigned - i can print it to any cell just fine. But calling the array reference overflows unless i use an absolute reference.

Comment: One version uses `ActiveSheet` the other specifies the workbook. You may think they are referencing the same, but `Sheets("X")` may not be your `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: Thanks Kyle -X is the activesheet. NUM is correct and can be msgbox'ed or printed to any cell just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is clearly with whatever value `NUM` has when the error is thrown; `NUM` is outside the bounds of `ARRAYX`.

Add error handling and debug accordingly with your findings:

```
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    'your code

    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "Max legal value for 'NUM' is:" & UBound(ARRAYX,1) & vbNewLine _
         & "The value of 'NUM' is: " & NUM & vbNewLine _
         & "Taken from cell (" & i & "," & j & ")" & vbNewLine _
         & "Fix the data in the worksheet and try again."
```

---

It works with `A1` because the value in cell `A1` is a legal index for your `ARRAYX` array. It fails with `(i,j)` because the value in cell `(i,j)` is outside the bounds of the array.

---

Reading through the comments, a number of things need to be debunked:

- `Cells("A1")` isn't an *absolute reference*. `Cells("$A$1")` is. "Absolute references" refers to the way a cell address is expressed; absolute columns (`$A`), and absolute rows (`$1`). Whether you use an absolute cell reference or not makes no difference whatsoever.
- The smallest possible scope in VBA is *procedure level*, which means a variable can be declared anywhere in the body of a procedure. `Dim` statements are not executable: VBA allocates the memory space for a procedure's declarations before a single line runs in that procedure. Stepping through code (<kbd>F8</kbd> while debugging) skips `Dim` statements for that reason (you cannot break on a `Dim` statement). A code block inside a procedure is not a scope: variables declared inside an `If` or `With` or `Do` or whatever other possible code blocks, is in the same scope as any variable declared at the top of a procedure.

Comment: Thanks but as I mentioned I can print NUM to any cell and it is exactly as expected every time.

Comment: @DanS ok, so what's `UBound(ARRAYX,1)` and how does it compare to `NUM`?

Comment: Well NUM starts at 0 and by the end of the loop it is 250, which is the number of rows in the array.

Comment: Just to be clear, NUm is correct, can be printed to any cell and is always as designed.

Comment: Also the array works fine and any cell can be called by putting the numbers into the code. The problem is when using NUM as the row ref for the array - it overflows when done this way.

Comment: Which part of *what is the upper bound of ARRAYX* is unclear?

Comment: Sorry if I m not clear. -  the upper bound of ARRAYX is 250, and it "compares to NUM" by being the same at the end of the loop as there are 250 rows in the array.

Comment: Well a "subscript out of range" error means you're accessing an array outside of its bounds. My answer assumes the problem is with `ARRAYX(NUM,2)`, based on the top snippet "working" with `NUM` being an unknown value in cell `A1`; at one point in your loop, `NUM` is taking a value from `Cells(i,j)` that is outside the bounds of the array (is your array 1-based? 0-based? is 250 the number of elements in the array or its actual upper bound?) - did you even *try* adding an error handler as suggested?

Comment: Thanks Mat - NUM is fine and when that number is added to the array in VBa it works - ie, NUM is 1, ARRAYX(1,1) is fine, ARRAYX(NUM,1) overflows

Comment: But as I said only when NUm is defined by an (i,j) INSIDE the loop, when its got from A1 it works..

Comment: This makes no difference whatsoever. What matters is THE VALUE, not where it's coming from. Add error handling and verify the values of `i` and `j` *when the error is thrown*, and more importantly **the value of that cell** - i.e. learn to debug your code. And "out of bounds" isn't "overflow", if you're getting an "overflow" then you're overflowing the Integer type, most likely with a value greater than 32,767. So, not "overflow", "out of bounds". Correct terminology helps being correctly understood when people aren't looking at your screen.

Comment: Odd, @DanS, you come here asking for advice on how to make your code work, then when someone gives you a suggestion (which I'm going to go out on a limb and say is the root of your problem), you tell them that it is wrong without ever attempting to implement what has been suggested to you. Mat's Mug has much more patience than I...

Comment: @DanS - why don't you add in the 2 lines where: **1)** The call to `Test()` is made, and **2)** where the array being passed into `Test()` is defined.

Comment: I can see I'm not being clear but I am trying! What I am saying is if I put ARRAY(1,1) into the vba code it prints 99. NUM is 1. But if I put ARRAY(NUM,1), I get the error. BUT ONLY if I dimension from within the loop. IF I say A1 is 1, and NUM = A1, all is well.

Comment: Thanks I will try your error handler code when I get it to go past the first loop  - at the moment NUM is 0 because thats the number I start on .(Max legal NUM in the array is 250 as stated) - it just wont accpet NUm as a part of the array query unless num was assigned from a cell outside the loop

Comment: Ok. For what it's worth, I give up. Good luck. You have a runtime error, you want to debug the runtime error. Add a runtime error handling subroutine and break in that handler, verify your values. Or, keep thinking A1 makes any kind of a difference.

Comment: Thanks for trying. All values are as expected - it is dimensioning NUM from inside the loop that is causing the problem - NUM says its 1, it is 1, putting a 1 in myself or assigning from an ("A1" type)  cell on the worksheet with a 1 in it works. But when that cell with the 1 in it is pointed to via (i,j) inside the loop I get the error. But Num is still 1 at all times - I promise

Comment: @DanS - There is no possible way that your interpretation is correct. See [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40225933/dimensioning-a-variable-inside-a-loop/40226456#comment67715598_40225933) from earlier. Not only are you not using equivalent code in your 2 examples (as pointed out by [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40225933/dimensioning-a-variable-inside-a-loop/40226456#comment67716381_40225933)), variable ***storage*** has nothing to do with a subscript error. You won't get far debugging this until you let go of the assumption that you know the cause.

Comment: @DanS, then your problem is that the element does not xist in the array, ie arrayx(NUM, 2) does not exist

Comment: @Dan S. This is NOT a hard problem to solve. You have had good advice from several advanced VBA users, and you have ignored them all. They have not given up on solving your problem, they have given up on you. Restating your *beliefs* will not change or fix the bug. Add the error handler, discover what i, j, and Cells(i,j) is, and get on with it.

Comment: It seems my machine is behaving strangely - giving differnt answers after a rest. Mat's error handling is much appreciated.

Comment: FWIW it could also be that your array's LBound is 1 and Cells(i,j) isn't on the sheet you think it is and it's returning 0 which is out of bounds...